# Uploading audio file buffer fails when uploading to aws s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Here is my frontend code:

```
 let audioFile = require("assets/hello.wav");
    let blob = new Blob([audioFile], { type: "audio/wav" });

    try {
      await customFetch(`${API_URL}/new-audio-message`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          audio: blob,
          cloneId: cloneId,
        }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Here is is how I upload the file to s3:

```
const { audio } = JSON.parse(event.body);
const fileKey = `${sub}/${cloneId}/audio/${uuidv4()}.wav`;
const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(audio));

  try {
    await s3
      .putObject({
        Bucket: PUBLIC_BUCKET,
        Key: fileKey,
        Body: buffer,
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
```

The file uploads to s3 **but** the file size for every audio file is `155 B` irrespective of the length of the audio file.

Comment: maybe the content of each file is the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the `audio` file is not being properly converted to a buffer before being sent to S3. The line `const buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(audio))` is attempting to convert the `audio` object to a string and then create a buffer from that string. However, this is not the correct way to convert a `Blob` object to a buffer.

**Updated frontend code**

```
let audioFile = require("assets/hello.wav");
let blob = new Blob([audioFile], { type: "audio/wav" });

const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
reader.onloadend = async () => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(reader.result);
  try {
    await customFetch(`${API_URL}/new-audio-message`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        audio: buffer,
        cloneId: cloneId,
      }),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**Updated backend code**

```
const { audio } = JSON.parse(event.body);
const fileKey = `${sub}/${cloneId}/audio/${uuidv4()}.wav`;

try {
  await s3
    .putObject({
      Bucket: PUBLIC_BUCKET,
      Key: fileKey,
      Body: audio,
    })
    .promise();
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```